# Xmlreader and remote large file

Tags: c#, large-files, xmlreader

I have to read a remote xml file with XmlReader but sometimes I have an exception :

> system.net.webexception the operation has timed out.

But i don't know why because it can work or not with the same file.

Anyone have a solution.

Comment: You have not provided nearly enough information. Where is this remote location? How are you accessing it? How are you reading? How large is this large file? At least post your code that errors.

Comment: You need to give us more information. How do you read the remote file? Using shared folders, HTTP, FTP, or something else? Could you describe how do you process it, e.g. are there long pauses during the processing? Even better would be a short code that exhibits this problem.

Comment: This file is on local network and is generated dynamically when i go to the url of the file. I use xmlreader to read the file and i use the url of the remote xml to construct xmlreader.

Comment: What does the URL look like? Does it start with `http://`? And you didn't answer other questions, like: how do you process the XML, in *detail*, ideally showing us the code.

Answer (score 1):

As per the description, seems like your network is dropping connections or in other terms its flaky. Hence its a network problem and not a problem with the code.

Comment: An assumption at best. I don't know how you can determine this just by the details in the question.